# Certain applications seem to ignore font smoothing at low sizes

Tags: macos, font

Certain applications seem to disable ALL font-smoothing (including AA) at certain small font sizes. This is by far most annoying in mathematica.

[image: 1/2+x^2, the 2 in x^2 is smaller and not smoothed.]

When I have to export to HTML or rasterize text for any other reason, the images are exported using the computer font smoothing. So, when I export to HTML, equations with fractions or exponents are rendered weirdly.

Is there any way to fix this? Is it a problem specific to the affected applications? Or is it an OS X issue?

I know there used to be a setting which controlled the minimum size below which font-smoothing would be disabled. I seem to recall setting it to the max, but now the setting no longer exists.